# Reading a matrix from Excel with pandas gives 2 different outputs depending on the PC used

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following Matrix stored in Excel:

[image: Matrix Excel]

I read this matrix with the following code:

```
def load_matrix(path):
    """
    Load the matrix file.
    Returns a numpy array.
    """
    xl= pd.ExcelFile(path)
    matrix = xl.parse('Matrix')
    return matrix
```

On most of the PC (called PC1), the output is:

[image: PC1 output]

This is the desired output, with the column/line names as an index.
However, on a second PC (called PC2), the output is:

[image: PC2 output]

This is a problem for me since the code then accesses the data in the following way, which only works with the output from PC1.

```
Mat.at["E1", "E1"]
```

**Version detail:**

PC1:

- Python 3.7.1
- xlrd 1.2.0
- xlsxwriter 1.1.4
- spyder 3.3.3
- pandas 0.23.4
- numpy 1.16.1

PC2:

- Python 3.7.2
- xlrd 1.2.0
- xlsxwriter 1.1.5
- spyder 3.3.3
- pandas 0.24.1
- numpy 1.16.1

My guess is that the small difference in versions results in a problem. How could I change the code to make it compatible with both, and to output the output from PC1?

Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried specifying the index column? does it give the same results?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: @nickthefreak Indeed, using `pd.read_excel(matrix_path, index_col=0)` instead of `pd.read_excel(matrix_path)` gives the correct output. I guess I could use this to read the excel instead of `.parse()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper answer here since the test worked :)

Basically, the [ExcelFile.parse](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) takes the same parameters as the [.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method, you can see documentation for exact details.

Not sure why the index column is read differently between PCs (might be the libraries or maybe even python versions), but the best way to future proof is to explicitly set the index_col parameter.

this then becomes:

```
xl= pd.ExcelFile(path).parse(index_col=0)
```

or:

```
xl = pd.read_excel(matrix_path, index_col=0)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a proper answer. I did not know they took both the same parameters :)